# Spring Boot - RequestMapping not working in RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I´m building a Rest login service but when I tried to access the landing page I get this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

The RestController code in really simple

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

private VoterAcces voterAccess;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String landing() {
    return "Landing page por Voters System";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object getVI(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
    return this.voterAccess.getUser(userInfo.getEmail(), userInfo.getPassword());

}
```

Im not really sure why I get that and not the String "Landing page por Voters System"

Comment: You annotated the class with `@RestController` but expect a welcome page instead of a resource? If you want to have both, you should annotate the class with `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`.

Comment: or he can move it to an other controller since he has getVI which  treats RestRquests

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off static resource handling:

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false # Disable default resource handling.
```

More info can be found in [properties section of Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).